# Sections compiling with the wrong numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Long story short I recently had to re-install all of TeX-live on my ubuntu machine. When trying to recompile my analysis document, I got a clean compile; however now the section numbers are all out-of-whack. For instance, the sections go from section 1 to section 6 to section (12 I think). instead of 1,2,3 as they did before. I have not changed the document any except typing some more at the end of it. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks,slashed,xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\setenumerate[1]{label=(\alph*)}
\setenumerate[2]{label=(\roman*)}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand{\NOT}{\sim}\newcommand{\AND}{\wedge}\newcommand{\OR}{\vee}
\newcommand{\twolinebrace}{\rlap{$\smash{\raisebox{.5\height}{\bigg   \}}}$}}
\newlength{\LHS}\newlength{\RHS}
\settowidth{\LHS}{$P \OR (Q \OR R)$}\settowidth{\RHS}{$(P \AND Q)     \OR     (P\AND R)$}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}p{\LHS}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}p{\RHS}<{$}}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %


\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage{changes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\def    \bn{\mathbb N}
\def    \bz{\mathbb Z}
\def    \bq{\mathbb Q}
\def    \br{\mathbb R}
\def    \bc{\mathbb C}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremprework{\bigskip\hrule}
\theorempostwork{\hrule\bigskip}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}


\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
\psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{prop}[section]{Proposition}

\definechangesauthor[name={Fr. Thomas Moore}, color=violet]{TM}
\definechangesauthor[name={Michael Dykes}, color=blue]{MD}
\definechangesauthor[name={Larkin Griffin}, color=green]{LG}

\title{Real and Complex Analysis}
\author{Michael Dykes and Croix Snapp}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Logic, Set Theory, Functions, and Relations.}
\section{Mathematical Logic.}
\subsection{Introduction.}
\small{Analysis is all about the theory behind Calculus. In this course, we do not take for granted such notions as what the set $\br$ of real numbers is; rather we carefully define $\br$ by `building' it out of other sets - beginning with the set $\bn$ of Natural Numbers. Numbers and number systems (i.e. $\bn, \bz, \bq, \br,$ and $\bc$) are the `building-blocks' of Analysis. Here in this book, we do not merely state the properties of the Real Number System, but we derive them. 

However, \deleted[id=MD,remark=blah blah blah]{Would you like any toast?} before we do that (and we shall in Chapter 1), we first \deleted[id=MD,remark=blah blah blah]{present}  this introductory chapter - Chapter 0 - in order to give the reader the tools needed to carry on this study of the branch of mathematics known as Analysis. Here, we present a `brief' review of Mathematical Logic, Set Theory, Functions, and Relations; and we `informally' define a few sets of which we shall make frequent use of in Analysis. All of them (or most of them) shall be dealt with more formally in the next chapter.} 

\section{Basic Set Theory.}
\subsection{Introduction.}
\textquestiondown What is a set? The following definitions and examples shall attempt to clarify these questions.

\begin{defn}[Set]A \textbf{set} is a collection of objects called     \textbf{members} of this set. We shall typically use capital letters, $X,Y,\ldots$ to denote sets; and lowercase letters, $x,y,\ldots$ to denote elements of a set.\\
If $x$ is an element of the set $X,$ we write:
\[x\in X.\]
and say that $x$ is a member of $X,$ or that $x$ belongs to $X.$ If $x$  is \textit{not} an element of $X,$ we write:
\[x\notin X.\]
\end{defn}

\section{Functions.}
\subsection{Introduction.}
Functions are of fundamental importance to all branches of mathematics. The concept of a function has undergone quite a bit of change over the past several centuries. Over this time, this concept has been separated from any connections it previously had to arithmetic, algorithmic, or geometric ideas. So we can now present the modern set-theoretical definition of a function as we do below.

\begin{defn}[Function]
Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then a \textbf{function} or \textbf{map from $X$ to $Y$} is a rule, which, for each element of $X,$ specifies \textit{exactly one} element of $Y.$ We denote a function by
\[
    f \colon X \to Y \q x \mapsto f(x)
\]
\end{defn}

\subsection{Function Composition.}

\begin{prop}
Let $f \colon X \to Y, g \colon  Y \to U, h \colon U \to V$ be functions. Then the compositions $(h \circ g) \circ f$ and $h \circ (g \circ f) \colon X \to V$ are well-defined and
\[
    (h \circ g) \circ f = h \circ (g \circ f)
\]
\end{prop}

\subsection{Injections, Surjections, and Bijections.}
We now take a look at some properties of functions. We define what an  injection, surjection, and a bijection is. These are rather important classifications and are ones that you have probably encountered before.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apparently with the MWE I have posted, there is no problem. But with my full document I do get the problem mentioned. So, I took my MWE above and added the "full" preamble I had and still no issues the sectioning was fine. Then I added all of Chapter 0 and re-compiled. Voila there the issue reasserted itself. Sectioning was numbered: 1,6,12,17. When compiling with latex I could not compile due to my definition of proposition. I had to compile with XeTex to get a proper compile then the messed up sectioning. I'll post my definition of proposition by editing my MWE.

Comment: It seems that the odd section numbering also occurs at the subsection level. By that I mean that in the same section, I see subsections numbered: 1.1, 1.2, then 2.1. The 2.1 subsection of *section 1* is following my first proposition which leads me to believe that there is something suspect to the way in which I have defined my proposition environment. Any help redefining it is to be appreciated.

Comment: even after edits the MWE still shows no problem? Section numbering seems normal to me...

Comment: unrelated to numbering but `\small` does not take an argument so in `\small{...}` in your first section, the `{}` are not the argument of `\small` they are a group, and `\small` will apply for the rest of the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I wasn't sure how much to add but once I add a single (from my entire document) example of a proposition, then the sectioning starts to exhibit problems. Guess I need to add that to the MWE, huh?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Now the error is reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of \newshadedtheorem is wrong. The optional argument [section] should go at last. Compare:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{prop}[section]{Proposition} %wrong, proposition increase section counter

\begin{document}

\section{a}
\begin{prop}
blub
\end{prop}
\section{b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section] %correct

\begin{document}

\section{a}
\begin{prop}
blub
\end{prop}
\section{b}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does work, but now my propositions no longer are shaded. But that does solve the section numbering issue. Thanks!

Comment: You naturally should use `\newshadedtheorem` in your document. I switched to \newtheorem only for the sake of a smaller example.

Comment: The same problem had been driving me nuts, and now it's fixed. Thanks!!